# AWS Performance simulation by region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Our cloud region is located at N. Virginia AWS and we need to move it to nearest area to the Middle East where all traffic and requests are originate from. But before doing that is there a way to simulate the performance between regions at AWS before deciding to move to the new region or not?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that some services, features and hardware are specific to regions. So, before migrating we need to check if it is available in the target Region are not. AWS rolls out them region-by-region, usually the North Virginia is the first one.

From a network perspective use [cloudping.info](https://www.cloudping.info/) for latencies. For me Mumbai provides better latency from where I am working as of now.

[image]